# PHP Split URL to create "You Are Here" Navigation

Tags: php

To get this pages "You are here" it would read the following;

> HOME => questions => 28240416 => php-split-url-to-create-you-are-here-navigation

I would like to use PHP to get the URL and split after the domain name separating all via the forward slash '/' to create a "You are here" content.

In addition I would like to replace all '-', '_', '%20' with ' ' and capitalize the first letter of the split.

Mock URL Examples;

URL: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4423554/tim-marshall

Would return;

> Home => Users => 4423554 => Tim-marshall

### My latest attempt

My latest attempt has only produces the last part of the string;

```
<?php
    $url = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";;
    $parts = explode('/', rtrim($url, '/'));
    $id_str = array_pop($parts);
    // Prior to 5.4.7 this would show the path as "//www.example.com/path"
    echo '<h1>'.$id_str.'</h1>';
?>
```

### Another Attempt

```
<?php
    $url = 'somedomainDOTcom/animals/dogs';
    $arr = explode($url, '/');
    unset($arr[0]);
    $title = '';
    foreach($arr as $v) $title .= ucfirst($v).'>>';
    $title =trim($title,'>');
    echo "\n<br>".$title;
?>
```

Comment: Could we have a few examples of mock URLs?

Comment: Just edited again @LawrenceCherone, one of many attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode`, `array_unshift`, `array_map`, `ucfirst`, and `implode`:

```
$url = '/this/is/the/path'; // or $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].. avoid $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

$url = str_replace(array('-', '_', '%20'), ' ', $url); // Remove -, _, %20

// your choice of removing extensions goes here    

$parts = array_filter(explode('/', $url)); // Split into items and discard blanks

array_unshift($parts, 'Home'); // Prepend "Home" to the output

echo implode(
    ' =&gt; ',
    array_map(function($item) { return ucfirst($item); }, $parts)
); // Capitalize and glue together with =>
```

Output:

```
Home =&gt; This =&gt; Is =&gt; The =&gt; Path
```

or in resolved HTML:

```
Home => This => Is => The => Path
```

Removing extensions is the trickier part if you have stray dots in the URI. If it's a guarantee that only the filename will have the dot, you can use:

```
$url = explode('.', $url);
$url = $url[0]; // Returns the left half
```

but if there's no guarantee, and you know what the possible extensions are, you can just use `str_replace` again:

```
$url = str_replace(array('.php','.html','.whatever'), '', $url);
```

but since you're only going to be running this script in the PHP, context, it's probably as simple as:

```
$url = str_replace('.php', '', $url)
```

Comment: Cam you please make it so '-' are replaced with ' ' and the .suffix doesn't show?

Comment: got the replace done, don't know why I asked for that when it is simple. Just removing the, eg; .php

Comment: This does not work on my index page: Home => Index  upon being on the index page, this is the home...

Comment: @TimMarshall That's what you would call an "exceptional circumstance." Not hard to account for if you just apply some critical thinking to the answer that has been provided for you. Wrap the `array_unshift` and `echo` lines with `if ($parts[0] !== 'index') { ... }` and then add an `else { echo 'Home'; }`.

Comment: Believe me, I did try and made a good couple of attempts searching ther internet and whatnot but every time I failed. Thank you for your modified answer :)

Comment: Next my goal is to wrap each one to make them a link!

Answer (score 0):

### Example:

```
<?php
    $url = "testdomain.com/Category/Sub-Category/Files.blah";;
    $chunks = array_filter(explode('/', $url));
    echo "<h1>".implode(' &gt;&gt; ', $chunks)."</h1>";
?>
```

### Usage:

For your current page, replace

```
$url = "testdomain.com/Category/Sub-Category/Files.blah";
```

With

```
$url = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

And it will return your "Where are you" Navigation.